# Powershell Foreach usage and syntax

Tags: powershell, csv, variables, foreach

I'm attempting to script the creation of accounts in active directory using a csv file. Unfortunately I'm new to PowerShell and scripting in general and am facing difficulty managing a foreach() loop which is intended to handle each of the columns in the csv document I import.

I suspect that I cannot define my variables in one block after foreach() like I have, but am unsure and would appreciate some guidance. Specifically, the purpose of the code is read a csv document and assign each item to a variable that it then uses to create a service account with those values.

The Ideal situation is one where I can create a csv with several hundred rows, execute the script and end with several hundred matching service accounts.

```
$SVC = (import-csv C:\users\me\desktop\Test.csv -header("Name", "Pass", "WhatDo", "Location", "Domain")) `
foreach($variable in %SVC) {

    $name = $SVC.Name
    $Pass = $SVC.Pass
    $WhatDo = $SVC.WhatDo
    $Location = $SVC.Location
    $Domain = $SVC.Domain


        New-ADuser `
            -Name $name `
            -AccountPassword (Convertto-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force) `
            -CannotChangePassword $true `
            -Description $WhatDo `
            -DisplayName $name `
            -Enabled $true `
            -GivenName $name `
            -PasswordNeverExpires $True `
            -Office $Location `
            -Path "OU=Service-Accounts, Ou=Accunts, OU=_CORP, DC=$Domain, DC=net" `
            -SamAccountName $name `
            -UserPrincipleName $name + "@" + $domain + ".net" `

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

    Get-ADUser `
        -Identity $name | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf "Group1","Group2","Group3"  

    }
```

Comment: Please describe what is the problem you're having - otherwise your question may face closure: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: `foreach ($item in $SVC)` - But there are many many online exmaples on creating AD Users from csv, excel, txt etc. ...

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong in your code, not just the foreach.

But let's start with that: `foreach ($variable in $SVC)` means that `$variable` will have the the current item inside your loop, yet you are accessing `$SVC` in your loop which is still referring to the original collection. `$variable` is not a good name either, so you should change that to something more meaningful. Also, you wrote `%SVC` instead of `$SVC`.

You are also using backtick (`) a lot, sometimes incorrectly. You should only use it when your cmdlet invokation spans multiple lines. In the case of `Import-Csv` it's not, yet there's backtick at the end. There's also one on the last line of `New-ADUser`. Some prefer to use [Parameter Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) instead of backticks, but's thats a matter of taste.

Considering you are creating service accounts, I would write the first part like this:

```
$serviceAccounts = Import-Csv C:\users\me\desktop\Test.csv -Header Name,Pass,WhatDo,Location,Domain

foreach($serviceAccount in $serviceAccounts) {
```

Then inside your loop you can access the indivdual properties through `$serviceAccount`:

```
$name = $serviceAccount.Name
```

Also, PowerShell expands variables when using double quotes, so `-UserPrincipleName` can be written like this: `-UserPrincipleName "$name@$domain.net"`

Comment: I'm very new to scripting, and grateful for each bit of help. Thank you for your comment since it allowed some immediate progress as well helping me to grasp more quickly the nature of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using ForEach-Object rather than foreach.

It would be something like:

```
$SVC = (Import-CSV C:\users\me\desktop\Test.csv -header("Name", "Pass", "WhatDo", "Location", "Domain")) 
$SVC | ForEach-Object {

        New-ADuser `
            -Name $_.Name `
            -AccountPassword (Convertto-SecureString $_.Pass -AsPlainText -Force) `
            -CannotChangePassword $true `
            -Description $_.WhatDo `
            -DisplayName $_.Name `
            -Enabled $true `
            -GivenName $_.Name `
            -PasswordNeverExpires $True `
            -Office $_.Location `
            -Path "OU=Service-Accounts, Ou=Accunts, OU=_CORP, DC=$Domain, DC=net" `
            -SamAccountName $_.Name `
            -UserPrincipleName $_.Name + "@" + $_.Domain + ".net" 

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

    Get-ADUser `
        -Identity $_.Name | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership `
        -MemberOf "Group1","Group2","Group3"  

    }
```

$_ represents the current item in the pipeline. ($SVC in your case, which was the wrong variable anyways.) It's less code and I think it's a cleaner way of doing things!

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I need all the help I can get, and your answer gave me an idea of where I've been going wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `$SVC` to `$SVCs` then `foreach ($SVC in $SVCs)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can do it.(Don't forget the delimiter)

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\csv.csv -Header "a","b","c" -Delimiter ";"
foreach($row in $csv){
    $row.a
    $row.b
    $row.c
}
```

Here are some more examples how foreach works:
Take a look https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html

```
Examples

Loop through an array of strings:

 $trees = @("Alder","Ash","Birch","Cedar","Chestnut","Elm")

 foreach ($tree in $trees) {
   "$tree = " + $tree.length
 }

Loop through a collection of the numbers, echo each number unless the number is 2:

 foreach ($num in 1,2,3,4,5) {
  if ($num -eq 2) { continue } ; $num
 }

Loop through a collection of .txt files:

  foreach ($file in get-ChildItem *.txt) {
    Echo $file.name
  }
```